# How to make the data from Firestore in to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I make the value return outside the onSnapshot function?

```
function checkIfExisting(){

  const collection = firebase.firestore().collection("audit");
  const getCaseID = collection.where("caseID", "==", "00001234");

  getCaseID.onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
    let wordLists = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    //get all the scanned words under "word" field in the Firestore Database
        wordLists.push(doc.data().word);
    });

    console.log("words: ", wordLists);// return a value

  });

  console.log("words1: ", wordLists);// undefined

  }
```

I knew that the `console.log("words1: ", wordLists)` is outside the function that's why I can't get its value. Could you please give me an idea on how can I call it outside the function (if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access it outside, you can use `Promise`:

```
function checkIfExisting(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const collection = firebase.firestore().collection("audit");
   const getCaseID = collection.where("caseID", "==", "00001234");

   getCaseID.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
     let wordLists = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
     //get all the scanned words under "word" field in the Firestore Database
        wordLists.push(doc.data().word);
          resolve(wordLists);
     });
     console.log("words: ", wordLists);// return a value
  });
```

Then to access outside do the following:

```
checkIfExisting().then((result) => {
   console.log(result);
});
```

`result` will contain the `wordLists`

Check the following for more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `wordLists` is defined (by using `let`) inside the callback (function) passed to `onSnapshot`. Even ignoring the fact that that's an asynchronous operation (which Peter's answer tackles using a Promise) – you cannot access a variable defined inside a function outside of that function.

You can learn about variable scoping [here on SO, quick n dirty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) – or in Kyle's excellent *you don't know JavaScript* series, which is [available freely on github](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) or in print. Part 2, *Scope & Closures*.
Also, to actually understand Peter's answer, *Async & Performance*.