# How to assign data fetched from Firestore.collection() .get() .then() method to a global variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch data (a particular field in a doc) from Firebase FireStore → Assign that value to global variable → console.log that value.

**My Research till now:**

1. I tried assigning the value to global variable → NOT WORKING
2. I tried returning the fetched value

`var a = firestore.collection("collection1").doc("doc1").get().then(){ return doc.data().FIELD}`

3. removing the return keyword from the above

Currently I am doing nested code like console.log() inside the then().

**What my code looks like now**

```
var a = "BEFORE";
console.log(a); // BEFORE
firestore.collection("collection1").doc("doc1").then(
  function(doc) {
    const myData = doc.data();
    a = myData.Reciept_Series;
    console.log(a); // DESIRED_VALUE
  }
)
console.log(a); //BEFORE
```

How can I make `a = DESIRED_VALUE` ie. How can I use the value that I got from FireStore .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is not **where** you access the value, but **when** you access it. The `console.log(a);` outside of the callback runs **before** the `a = myData.Reciept_Series;` has run, and there.s no way to delay it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068260/how-to-make-the-data-from-firestore-in-to-a-global-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code, the handler is called as soon as the Firebase returns your data

```
function handler(a) {
  // here you can work with a
}

firestore.collection("collection1").doc("doc1")
.then(doc => doc.data)
.then(myData => myData.Reciept_Series)
.then(handler)
.catch(console.error); // to debug: make sure the error (if any) is always reported
```

If you want to wait for the data, use async/await pattern:

```
(async function() {
  var a = await firestore.collection("collection1").doc("doc1")
    .then(doc => doc.data)
    .then(myData => myData.Reciept_Series)
  // here you can work with a
})();
```

Keep in mind that the Promise (returned by `then()`) is run **asynchronously**, so your code is not executed in top-down order, but as another task.

You can call `await` on top level just in [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), otherwise the main thread would be blocked by it. See the support table at the bottom of the linked page.

Your global variable is assigned, but asynchronously. Give the code some time and then click the following button:

```
<button onclick="console.log(a)">Log data</button>
```